# How to loop through subscribe method in Angular 5

Tags: angular

I'm trying to loop through the subscribe method. However the order in which the data is pushed within this array `this.fieldsList` is not consistent. What could be the reason?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import { DragulaService } from 'ng2-dragula';
import {MatTableDataSource, MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material';
import { DataService } from '../../data.service';
import { ManufacturerAddTabComponent } from './manufacturer-add-tab/manufacturer-add-tab.component';
import { ManufacturerEditTabComponent } from './manufacturer-edit-tab/manufacturer-edit-tab.component';
import { ManufacturerDeleteTabComponent } from './manufacturer-delete-tab/manufacturer-delete-tab.component';
import { ManufacturerOrderTabsComponent } from './manufacturer-order-tabs/manufacturer-order-tabs.component';
import { ManufacturerAddFieldComponent } from './manufacturer-fields/manufacturer-add-field/manufacturer-add-field.component';
import { ManufacturerEditFieldComponent } from './manufacturer-fields/manufacturer-edit-field/manufacturer-edit-field.component';
import { ManufacturerDeleteFieldComponent } from './manufacturer-fields/manufacturer-delete-field/manufacturer-delete-field.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-manufacturer-tabs',
  templateUrl: './manufacturer-tabs.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./manufacturer-tabs.component.css']
})
export class TabsComponent implements OnInit {

  manufacturerId;
  tabId;
  tabsList;
  fieldsList = [];
  rearrangedFields;

  constructor(private _dataService: DataService, public dialog: MatDialog, private route:ActivatedRoute, private dragulaService: DragulaService) {
    dragulaService.dropModel.subscribe((value) => {
      this.onDropModel(value);
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(res => this.manufacturerId = res.id);
    this.listTabs();
  }

  addTab(){
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ManufacturerAddTabComponent, {
      width: '400px',
      data: { id: this.manufacturerId }
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      this.listTabs();
    });
  }

  editTab(tabId){
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ManufacturerEditTabComponent, {
      width: '400px',
      data: { id: this.manufacturerId, tabId: tabId }
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      this.listTabs();
    });
  }

  deleteTab(tabId){
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ManufacturerDeleteTabComponent, {
      width: '400px',
      data: { tabId: tabId }
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      this.listTabs();
    });
  }

  listTabs(){
    this.fieldsList = [];
    this._dataService.getManufacturerTabs(this.manufacturerId)
      .subscribe((response) => {
        this.tabsList = response;
        console.log(this.tabsList);
        for (let i=0; i<this.tabsList.length; i++){
          this.listFields(this.tabsList[i].id);
        }
      })
  }

  listFields(tabId){
    this._dataService.getManufacturerFields(tabId)
      .subscribe((response) => {
        this.fieldsList.push(response);
        console.log(this.fieldsList);
      })
  }

  orderTabs(){
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ManufacturerOrderTabsComponent, {
      width: '400px',
      data: this.tabsList
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      this.listTabs();
    });
  }

  addField(tabId){
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ManufacturerAddFieldComponent, {
      width: '400px',
      data: { id: tabId }
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      this.listTabs();
    });
  }

  editField(fieldId){
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ManufacturerEditFieldComponent, {
      width: '400px',
      data: { id: fieldId }
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      this.listTabs();
    });
  }

  deleteField(fieldId){
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ManufacturerDeleteFieldComponent, {
      width: '400px',
      data: { id: fieldId }
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      this.listTabs();
    });
  }

  onDropModel(args) {
      this.rearrangedFields = args[2].children;
      this.orderFields();
  }

  orderFields(){
    for(let i=0; i<this.rearrangedFields.length; i++){
      console.log(this.rearrangedFields[i].id + ' ' + (i+1));
      this._dataService.updateManufacturerFieldsOrder(this.rearrangedFields[i].id, i+1)
      .subscribe((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        this.listTabs();
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show where `listTabs` is called ?

Comment: I've updated the code.

Comment: added my answer have try ...

Comment: is that worked for you ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are doing it wrong way if you have multiple request then make use of `mergeMap`, right now issue with you code is you are doing async call for each id and each take different time to complete (so if you want to arrage it then you should push data in one array and sort it , below solution do that also for you)

In you first method `listTabs()`, code as below

```
   const ids = [];
   for (let i=0; i<this.tabsList.length; i++){
      ids.push(this.tabsList[i].id);
    }
   this._dataService.getManufacturerFields(ids)
   .subscribe(item => {
    this.items.push(item);
    /*
      sort items by original IDs order 
      because responses might arrived in unordered fashion
      due to network conditions
    */
    this.items.sort((a: Item, b: Item) => {
       const aIndex = ids.findIndex(id => id === a.id);
       const bIndex = ids.findIndex(id => id === b.id);
       return aIndex - bIndex;
    })
  });
```

in your service method , you can code like below

```
getManufacturerFields(ids: number[]): Observable<any> {
  return from(ids).pipe(
    mergeMap(id => <Observable<any>> this.httpClient.get(`item/${id}`))
  );
}
```

now if you want to arrange by id then you should do

---

you can also make use of `forkJoin` method which gives you output in order you send request but problem with this method is it waits for all request to compete.

```
getManufacturerFields(ids: number[]): Observable<any> {
  return <Observable<any>> forkJoin(
    ids.map((id) => {
      return <Observable<Post>> this.httpClient.get(`item/${id}`);
    })
  ).pipe(concatAll());
}
```

here is article might help you : https://blog.angularindepth.com/practical-rxjs-in-the-wild-requests-with-concatmap-vs-mergemap-vs-forkjoin-11e5b2efe293

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the loop is sync and the get is async. So the loop doesn't wait for the method `listFields` to finish iteration.